# Angular 14 and Jest (cannot run tests)

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am upgrading Angular version in my project to 14. But when I tried to run unit tests, I get the same error for all of them:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' from 'node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/config/setup-jest.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/config/setup-jest.js
      node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js
      setupJest.ts
```

This is the current jest configuration:

*jest.config.js*

```
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupJest.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/dist/'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "lodash-es": "lodash",
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
      diagnostics: {
        ignoreCodes: [151001]
      }
    }
  },
  restoreMocks: true,
  clearMocks: true
}

module.exports = config;
```

*setupJest.ts*

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

Comment: what jest version are you running? im using 27.4.7 but also get this error

Comment: I upgraded to v28 and it works

Answer (score 3):

So I was searching online for quite sometime then I came across this solution, hope it works for you as well.

In the jest.config.js file, if you are using the moduleDirectories config change it from  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', './'] to moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', __dirname]

Answer (score 1):

I wasnt able to fix the problem with the solution provided by @fadingBeat but it inspired me to change `'./'` to `'<rootDir>'`. So after updating jest, jest-preset-angular and angular to the latest version I got this fixed by using moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', `'<rootDir>'`], in my jest.config.js instead of ['node_modules', './']

I also had to add the transformIgnorePatterns entry to get rid of any unexpected token errors like described in the troubleshooting section of the jest-preset-angular documentation: https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/troubleshooting

This is my current jest.config.js

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@angular|rxjs)'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage/',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can do

1- Make sure you changed this in setup-jest.ts file

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest'; //from
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.mjs'; //to
```

2- add mjs to module file extensions

```
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'],
```

3- Map your ts config paths at the moduleNameMapper, you can add rootDir/ as prefix as a second parameter to pathsToModuleNameMapper if needed

```
 const { compilerOptions } = require('$tsconfigFilePath'); // replace $tsconfigFilePath with the actual tsconfigFilePath;

 const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

 module.exports = {
   moduleNameMapper: {
     ...pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
     tslib: 'tslib/tslib.es6.js',
   }
 }
```

4- This one is tricky if you are using ngrx replace the following, this might be fixed in future version, it really depends on which @nrwl/jest version you are using, mine as of now is 14.6.0

```
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset'); //from
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default; //to
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have this type of error, I usually add required path to Jest configuration in package.json:

```
"modulePaths": [
 "<rootDir>",
 "/path/to/required"
],
```

However, this approach is more suitable for situations where required path is, for example, `src/app/`.

For node_modules, I solved the problem by adding `"transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/?!@angular"],` to package.json Jest configuration.

Also, I would advise you to hit `npm install` from the root folder. Just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Update latest version of  `jest` , `jest-preset-angular` and  install `jest-environment-jsdom` solved the problem.

```
npm i jest@latest
npm i jest-preset-angular@latest
npm i jest-environment-jsdom
```